# Ayuda con consulta en AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, sql-server, asp.net

Estoy usando ASP.NET, C# y AJAX.
Lo que necesito hacer es mandar a llamar una cantidad *n* de preguntas para un examen, en donde esa cantidad *n* sea un número que el administrador registró previamente en un formulario que envía los datos a una base de datos. Ya conseguí hacer que mande a traer las preguntas de forma aleatoria del tema que se seleccionó, el problema es que no sé cómo mandar a llamar el número de preguntas que indicó el administrador.

Ese número de preguntas que contendrá el examen se guardan en una tabla de SQL Server 2012 llamada *dbo.tema*. En la siguiente imagen verán que hay 2 temas (exámenes) ingresados de prueba, con un número de 10 preguntas para cada uno. Por tanto, al mostrar el formulario del examen debería de mostrar solamente 10 preguntas aleatorias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un método para listar las preguntas del tema hecho en C# con parámetros que envío a la base de datos:

```
public List<Pregunta> ListarPreguntas(String codTema, String noPreguntas)
        {
            List<Pregunta> Lista = new List<Pregunta>();
            SqlConnection con = null;
            SqlCommand cmd = null;
            SqlDataReader dr = null;


            try
            {
                con = Conexion.getInstance().ConexionBD();
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand("spListarPreguntasPorTema", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@prmLimite", noPreguntas);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@prmCodTema", codTema);
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    //Creando objetos de Tema
                    Pregunta objTema = new Pregunta();
                    objTema.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["cod_pregunta"].ToString());
                    objTema.Preg = dr["pregunta"].ToString();

                    objTema.respuestas = RespuestaDAO.getInstance().ListarRespuestasPorPregunta(objTema.ID);


                    //Añadiendo a la lista de objetos
                    Lista.Add(objTema);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            return Lista;
        }
```

En en procedimiento almacenado tengo lo siguiente:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spListarPreguntasPorTema]
(@prmLimite int,
@prmCodTema int
)
AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP (@prmLimite) p.cod_pregunta, p.pregunta
        FROM dbo.pregunta AS p
        INNER JOIN dbo.tema AS t
        ON p.cod_tema = @prmCodTema AND @prmLimite = t.no_preguntas
        ORDER BY NEWID()
    END
```

En donde mando a llamar a las preguntas y éstas se ordenan de manera aleatoria.

Y ahora en mi *.js* tengo el siguiente método:

```
function cargarExamen(codTema) {
    var obj = JSON.stringify({
        codTema: codTema,
        noPreguntas: 9
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Examen.aspx/ListarPreguntas",
        data: obj,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            (xhr.status + " \n" + xhr.responseText, "\n" + thrownError);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var c = data.d;
            var htmlC = "";
            for (var n = 0; n < c.length; n++) {
                htmlC += '<div class="col-md-12"><b>' + c[n].Preg + '</b><br>';

                for (var n2 = 0; n2 < c[n].respuestas.length; n2++) {
                    var respuesta = c[n].respuestas[n2];

                    htmlC += '<div class="col-md-3"><input id="optPreg' + c[n].ID + respuesta.ID + '" type="radio" name="optPreg' + c[n].ID + '" value="' + respuesta.ID + '">'+
                    '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="optPreg' + c[n].ID + respuesta.ID + '">' + respuesta.Resp + '</label>';
                    htmlC += '</div>'

                }
                htmlC += '</div>';
            }

            $('.lstTema').css("display", "none");
            $('.lstExamen').css("display", "inline");
            $('#cntExamen').html(htmlC);
        }
    });
}
```

En la parte de `noPreguntas: 9` está así porque era un dato estático que dejé de prueba, lo que necesito es que en vez de un número estático sea el número de preguntas que indicó el administrador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifica el problema. Ya que quien sabe la cantidad de preguntas es el tema, no envíes un pedido con la cantidad de preguntas.

Tu método listar preguntas, solo va a recibir el tema sobre el cual listar.

```
public List<Pregunta> ListarPreguntas(String codTema)
```

Y lo primero que vas a hacer, es averiguar cuantas preguntas necesitas:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select no_preguntas from tema where cod_tema = @cod_tema", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@cod_tema", codTema);
int cant_preguntas = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Una vez que haces eso, en tu variable `cant_preguntas`, ya tenes la cantidad que necesitas, por lo cual no es necesario que lo mandes desde tu front-end

Comment: ¿Y cómo quedaría en la parte del .js? Porque igual las preguntas tienen que mostrarse aleatorias, y también tengo un procedimiento almacenado para mostrar cada respuesta.

Comment: no hay que cambiar nada. el front muestra lo que le manda el back. solo desaparece el parametro noPreguntas que no tiene sentido.

Comment: ¿Pero sí elimino la línea: noPreguntas: 9?

Comment: si si. no tiene sentido...

Comment: Estuve corrigiendo un par de cosas más y tu ayuda me funcionó, ¡gracias!